# How can i connect my .mdf database into vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, connection-string

I'm trying to connect my local .mdf file to vb.net and this argument exception pops up "Keyword not supported. Parameter name: attachdbfilename"

here's my code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

Dim con As MySqlConnection

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\almond\Desktop\TICKETING SYSTEM\TICKETING SYSTEM\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Try
        con.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connected!")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You will want the SqlConnection class for Microsoft SQL. MySQL is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using `MySqlConnection`, and that only must be used with `MySql` databases. You must use `SqlConnection`:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient;

Public Class Form1

Dim con As SqlConnection

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    con = New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\almond\Desktop\TICKETING SYSTEM\TICKETING SYSTEM\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Try
        con.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connected!")
       con.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```